# Find the centroid of a spherical triangle

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

Calculate the latitude and longitude of the centroid O of a spherical triangle ABC with the following vertices: A) Miami International Airport 25.793333, -80.290556, B) John F. Kennedy International Airport 40.639722, -73.778889, and C) Los Angeles International Airport 33.9425, -118.408056. Assume the earth is a perfect sphere.
I have studied problems on your website similar to the one above-mentioned. Also, I have searched the internet for a solution with no success. I have several books on Spherical Trigonometry which do not discuss a problem like this. Please help me solve this problem. I would appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Comment: Is $O$ underground?

Comment: No, O is on the surface of the spherical triangle.